# Javascript Remove Class for Specific Screen Size not working?

Tags: javascript, css

So I wrote a function that adds a `highlight` class whenever I click on a specific menu item and removes the `highlight` class if I were to click on a different menu item

My problem is that when I shrink my screen to mobile view, the `highlight` class is still applied and I don't know how to prevent it from showing up?

I used window.innerWidth but it doesn't seem to work when I shrink my screen

```
      const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
      const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

      const activeMenu = e => {
        const elem = document.querySelector('.highlight');

         // adds 'highlight' class to my menu item here
        if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
          e.target.className = 'navbar__links highlight';
        }
          

        // it doesn't remove the class 'highlight' when I shrink my screen
        // this only removes the 'highlight' class if I click on a different menu item

        if (elem || window.innerWidth < 768) {
          elem.classList.remove('highlight');
        }
      };

      menuLinks.addEventListener('click', activeMenu);


 // Tried to add resize event, but this didn't work, so not sure how 
 to write it 

      const removeActiveMenu = () => {
        const elem = document.querySelector('.highlight');

        if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
          elem.classList.remove('highlight');
        }
      };

      menuLinks.addEventListener('resize', removeActiveMenu);
```

Does anyone know how to prevent my `highlight` class from showing up on screen sizes below 768px?

I attempted to add a resize event below, but didn't work, so not sure how I am supposed to implement this?

Here is the HTML

```
  // Realized my Logo isn't highlighting the home nav when I click it
   <a href="#home" id="navbar__logo">COLOR</a>
    <div class="navbar__toggle" id="mobile-menu">
      <span class="bar"></span> <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </div>

   <ul class="navbar__menu">
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="homePage">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-us">About 
 Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__item">
        <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" 
 id="service">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navbar__btn">
        <a href="#sign-up" class=" button" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: How about making your actual CSS definition only apply to screen sizes using media queries like `@media all and (max-width:768px){}`? Then you don't have to care about the JS state whatsoever. You added no CSS to your question though, so maybe you want to get a working example going.

Comment: You would need a `resize` Event. You just have a `click` Event.

Comment: what do you mean? my function highlights my Home, About Us, Contact Us based on which one I clicked on. How else would you apply that effect without JS?

Comment: @StackSlave I tried to add one, but it didn't work, so I'm not sure how to write it. Do you know how I could write it?

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well to see if something is wrong there !!

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I added it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `querySelectorAll` along with `forEach` to get all `.navbar__links` and remove `highlight` class from them when you `resize` your `window` or put it into a `mobile` view.

You code was also producing console `errors` since you were trying to `remove` class from an `element` which does not exist when clicking in menu item and `window < 768`

```
//Remove class from others when click on li
  if (elem && window.innerWidth < 768 || elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
```

On resize function use this code:

```
//on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links');
  links.forEach(function(x) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      x.classList.remove('highlight'); //remove highlught class
    }
  })
});
```

I have fixed up your `code` and is working as expected.

**Live Demo:**

```js
const menu = document.querySelector('#mobile-menu');
const menuLinks = document.querySelector('.navbar__menu');

const activeMenu = e => {
  const elem = document.querySelector('.highlight');

  // adds 'highlight' class to my menu item here
  if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
    e.target.classList.add('highlight');
  }

  //Remove class from others when click on li
  if (elem && window.innerWidth < 768 || elem) {
    elem.classList.remove('highlight');
  }
};

//Click event on li
menuLinks.addEventListener('click', activeMenu);

//on resize
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links');
  links.forEach(function(x) {
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
      x.classList.remove('highlight'); //remove highlught class
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="navbar__menu">
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#home" class="navbar__links" id="homePage">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#about" class="navbar__links" id="about-us">About
        Us</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__item">
    <a href="#services" class="navbar__links" id="service">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li class="navbar__btn">
    <a href="#sign-up" class="button navbar__links" id="signup">Sign Up</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks so much this worked! do you think you know how to solve my other question on my page? It's similar to this question, except my issue is that the `highlight` class get's applied to my button in my navbar, but I don't want the button to get styled with the `highlight`

Comment: @Johnxr you are welcome :) Happy to help. Let me check that question and answer that one too. No problem.

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```js
function activeMenu(e) {
    let links = document.querySelectorAll('.navbar__links');
    if (window.innerWidth > 768) {
       links.forEach(link => {
           link.classList.remove("highlight");
       })
       e.classList.add("highlight");
    } else {
        e.classList.remove("highlight");
    }
}
```

```css
.highlight {color:red !important}
```

```html
<div id="mobile-menu">#mobile-menu</div>
<div class="navbar__menu">
    <div onclick="activeMenu(this)" class="navbar__links">navbar__links</div>
    <div onclick="activeMenu(this)" class="navbar__links">navbar__links</div>
    <div onclick="activeMenu(this)" class="navbar__links">navbar__links</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to add my Navbar logo. Do you know how I would apply the `highlight` class to the `Home` menu item if I were to click on my NavLogo?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you well - you can upload the code in full and explain the problem, and I will modify it